# React multiple echarts resize not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I have rendered 2 echarts components, but only 1 of them can resize when window size changed.
Kindly find the source code below and you can find out the issue when you resize your window
May I have some hints how I can solve this issue, Many thanks!

Structure Sample:

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import "@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import SimpleLine from "./chart1";

import { CContainer, CRow } from "@coreui/react";

export default function App2() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CContainer fluid>
        <CRow>
          <SimpleLine />
        </CRow>

        <CRow>
          <SimpleLine />
        </CRow>
      </CContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Echarts.js
both chart component has its own resize function listener:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as echarts from "echarts";



let xAxisDatas = [
  "Jan 01",
  "Jan 02",
  "Jan 02",
  "Jan 03",
  "Jan 04",
  "Jan 05",
  "Jan 06",
  "Jan 07",
  "Jan 08",
  "Jan 09",
  "Jan 10",
  "Jan 11",
  "Jan 12",
  "Jan 13",
  "Jan 14",
  "Jan 15",
  "Jan 16",
  "Jan 17",
  "Jan 18",
  "Jan 19",
  "Jan 20",
  "Jan 21",
  "Jan 22",
  "Jan 23",
  "Jan 24",
  "Jan 25",
  "Jan 26",
  "Jan 27",
  "Jan 28",
  "Jan 29",
  "Jan 30",
  "Jan 31",
  "Jan 01",
  "Jan 02",
  "Jan 02",
  "Jan 03",
  "Jan 04",
  "Jan 05",
  "Jan 06",
  "Jan 07",
  "Jan 08",
  "Jan 09",
  "Jan 10",
  "Jan 11",
  "Jan 12",
  "Jan 13",
  "Jan 14",
  "Jan 15",
  "Jan 16",
  "Jan 17",
  "Jan 18",
  "Jan 19",
  "Jan 20",
  "Jan 21",
  "Jan 22",
  "Jan 23",
  "Jan 24",
  "Jan 25",
  "Jan 26",
  "Jan 27",
  "Jan 28",
  "Jan 29",
  "Jan 30",
  "Jan 31","Jan 01",
  "Jan 02",
  "Jan 02",
  "Jan 03",
  "Jan 04",
  "Jan 05",
  "Jan 06",
  "Jan 07",
  "Jan 08",
  "Jan 09",
  "Jan 10",
  "Jan 11",
  "Jan 12",
  "Jan 13",
  "Jan 14",
  "Jan 15",
  "Jan 16",
  "Jan 17",
  "Jan 18",
  "Jan 19",
  "Jan 20",
  "Jan 21",
  "Jan 22",
  "Jan 23",
  "Jan 24",
  "Jan 25",
  "Jan 26",
  "Jan 27",
  "Jan 28",
  "Jan 29",
  "Jan 30",
  "Jan 31",
];


function SimpleLine() {
  const chartRef = useRef(null);
  let chartInstance2 = null;

 

  

let data = [
    {
      name: 'A',
      type: "line",
      smooth: false,
      showSymbol: true ,
      symbolSize:0.1,
      itemStyle: {color: '#0F4C5C'},
      lineStyle: {  width: 5 },
      areaStyle: {
          color: 'transparent',
          opacity: 0.5,
      },
          
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top',
        color: "#0F4C5C",
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: 'Bold',
        
      }
     ,
      data: [31,
        49,
        36,
        36,
        30,
        36,
        36,
        34,
        38,
        40,
        34,
        36,
        32,
        35,
        34,
        35,
        32,
        30,
        37,
        32,
        40,
        40,
        33,
        39,
        31,
        37,
        34,
        35,
        38,
        37,
        33,
        32,
        38,
        33,
        35,
        37,
        37,
        39,
        33,
        39,
        45,
        50,
        51,38,
        39,
        34,
        32,
        39,
        31,
        34,
        31,
        35,
        34,
        33,
        30,
        38,
        38,
        33,
        68,
        33,
        35,
        37,
        32,
        38,
        30,
        31,
        30,
        30,
        31,
        38,
        39,
        22,
        32,
        30,
        35,
        35,
        37,
        40,
        31,
        38,
        34,
        30,
        36,
        30,
        34,
        61,
        31,
        40,
        40,
        32,
        35,
        33,
        39,
        30,
        34,
        33,],
      markLine: {
        silent: true,
        lineStyle: {
          color: '#5d6664'
        },
        data: [
          /*{
            yAxis: 28
          },*/
          {
            yAxis: 38
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  ];

  var option1 = {
    textStyle: {
      color: "#545454",
      fontFamily: "Source Han Sans",//"Source Han Sans",
      fontWeight: "lighter",
      fontSize: '15',
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "axis",
      axisPointer: {
        type: "shadow", //line cross shadow
        crossStyle: {
          color: "#999"
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      data: ['A'],
      left: "50%",
      top: "2%",
      itemWidth: 10,
      itemHeight: 5
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "category",
      data: xAxisDatas,
      axisLabel: {
        margin: "10"
      },
      name: "xAxisName",
      nameLocation: "center",
      nameGap: 30,
      nameTextStyle: {
          padding: [5,0,0,0]
      },
      
      axisTick: {
        alignWithLabel: true,
        inside: true
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      name: "",
      type: "value",
      splitLine: {
        show: false
      }
    },
    dataZoom: [
      {
        show: false,
        realtime: true,
        start: 50,
        end: 100
      },
      {
        type: "inside", 
        realtime: true,
        start: 50,
        end: 100
      }
    ],
    grid: {
      left: '2%',
      top: '10%',
      right: '2%',
      bottom: '12%'
    },
    series: data,
   
  };

  const renderChart = () => {
    const renderedChartInstance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(chartRef.current);
    //const option2 = option1;
    if (renderedChartInstance) {
      chartInstance2 = renderedChartInstance;
    } else {
      chartInstance2 = echarts.init(chartRef.current);
    }
    //console.log(option1);
    chartInstance2.setOption(option1 , true);
  };


  useEffect(() => {

     renderChart()
 
   }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.onresize = function () {
        chartInstance2.resize();
    };
    return () => {
        chartInstance2 && chartInstance2.dispose();
    }; 
  }, []);

  return (

      <div ref={chartRef}  style={{ width: "100%" , height: "400px" }}></div>
        
    
    
    
  );
}

export default SimpleLine;
```

Comment: Without a running example it's hard to tell for sure, but I'd try to set by css the size relation between the two chart containers (e.g., `height:"50%"`) by including them in a larger container and resizing that container on window resize.

Comment: Hi kikon, source code has been provided, if possible, please take a look on that

Comment: I see, it's not the problem  I thought initially; I'm looking into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is the use of `window.onresize`. This works if there's only one component, but since there are multiple components and there's only one `window`, the value of `onresize` is *set* for each component (it is reassigned), so only the last one will take effect.

The solution is to replace that with [`window.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which will *add* an event handler for each component.

```js
   window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
       chartInstance2.resize();
   });
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-pare-m2dl36?file=/src/chart1.js:4876-4963) with your code and the small modification above.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clear explanation and it works well by using addEventListener. Thanks again !